# Upgrading to Fall Creators causes UWP animation to fail with "No installed components were detected. Animation target not specified."

Tags: c#, uwp, visual-studio-2017

I have a UWP project with an animation that worked fine prior to upgrading my workstation to the Windows 10 Fall Creators update. The app builds fine, but when I run it and tap on "Coming Soon", instead of the animation playing, now I get an exception.

I am running Visual Studio 2017 and my build targets Fall Creators.

Here is the XAML page:

```
<Page
x:Class="WaterCooler.JeopardyView"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:WaterCooler"
xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Page.Resources>
    <local:StringToUpperConverter  x:Key="StringToUpperConverter"/>
    <Storyboard x:Name="ClueReveal" Completed="ClueReveal_Completed">
        <DoubleAnimation 
            EnableDependentAnimation="True"
            Storyboard.TargetName="ClueGrid"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Grid.Height"
            From="0.0" To="300.0" Duration="0:0:1"/>
        <DoubleAnimation/>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Name="ClueHide" Completed="ClueHide_Completed">
        <DoubleAnimation 
            EnableDependentAnimation="True"
            Storyboard.TargetName="ClueGrid"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Grid.Height"
            From="300.0" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:1"/>
    </Storyboard>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Padding="0" Width="300" Height="600" Tapped="Grid_Tapped">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Width="300" Height="300" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="10" Background="Blue" Tapped="Grid_Tapped">
        <controls:DropShadowPanel Grid.Row="0" BlurRadius="0.0" ShadowOpacity="1.0" OffsetX="3" OffsetY="3" Color="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="35" Foreground="White" FontWeight="ExtraBold" FontFamily="MS Sans Serif" Text="{Binding FallbackValue='COMING SOON', Converter={StaticResource StringToUpperConverter}}" />
        </controls:DropShadowPanel>
    </Grid>

    <Grid x:Name="ClueGrid" Width="300" Height="0" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="10 5 10 10" Background="Blue" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <controls:DropShadowPanel  BlurRadius="0.0" ShadowOpacity="1.0" OffsetX="5" OffsetY="5" Color="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock FontSize="90" Foreground="Goldenrod" FontWeight="ExtraBold" FontFamily="MS Sans Serif" Text="$1000"/>
        </controls:DropShadowPanel>
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

And here is the code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at 
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234238

namespace WaterCooler
{
/// <summary>
/// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
/// </summary>
public sealed partial class JeopardyView : Page
{
    public JeopardyView()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        ClueIsRevealed = false;
    }

    private bool ClueIsRevealed { get; set; }

    private void Grid_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ClueReveal.GetCurrentState() != ClockState.Active)
        {
            if (ClueIsRevealed == false)
            {
                ClueReveal.Begin();
            }
            else
            {
                ClueHide.Begin();
            }
        }
    }

    private void ClueReveal_Completed(object sender, object e)
    {
        ClueIsRevealed = true;
    }

    private void ClueHide_Completed(object sender, object e)
    {
        ClueIsRevealed = false;
    }
}
}
```

And here is the exception:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFCD79C4008 (KernelBase.dll) in Water Cooler.exe: 
WinRT originate error - 0x800F1000 : 'Animation target not specified.'.
Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' in Water 
Cooler.exe
An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred 
in Water Cooler.exe but was not handled in user code
No installed components were detected.

Animation target not specified.

The program '[7948] Water Cooler.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a small catch here. You accidentally added an empty double animation below the first `DoubleAnimation`:

```
<Storyboard x:Name="ClueReveal" Completed="ClueReveal_Completed">
    <DoubleAnimation 
        EnableDependentAnimation="True"
        Storyboard.TargetName="ClueGrid"
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Grid.Height"
        From="0.0" To="300.0" Duration="0:0:1"/>
    <!-- REMOVE THIS <DoubleAnimation/> -->
</Storyboard>
```

This `DoubleAnimation` is empty and has no target specified and that causes the exception :-) .